# At which moment of Google App signing the protection occurs?

Tags: android-studio, cryptography, android-app-signing

When generating App Bundle in Android Studio, I can create keystores, populate them with keys, fill fields with whatever I want etc

[image]

At which moment here a protection occurs? Who and from whom is protected by these manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the guarantees that signing with an upload key provides:

- You have the guarantee that there is **no change made to your app between the time it's signed and the time it's uploaded** to the Play Console. This prevents attacks such as man-in-the-middle.
- Play will **not allow an App Bundle signed with a different key** be uploaded with that package name on the Play Store (even if your developer account has been compromised -- they would still need access to the upload key).

Once Google has verified that the App Bundle was effectively signed with the correct upload key, it will generate the APKs it serves to users and sign them with the so-called "app signing key". This gives additional guarantees:

- The devices of users of your app will only accept an update if it has been signed with the same app signing key. This prevents attacks where users would be tricked into installing an update from a different source. Since the APK would not be signed with the app signing key, the installation would be rejected.
- Users will also be protected if the APK has been tampered with since it was generated by Google since the signature will be invalidated and thus the installation rejected.